# Python tabulate for a nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a nested dictionary :

```py
   d = {"Tom":{"SchoolName1": "school_name_1","Classname1":"class_name_1","teacher1":"teachers_name1"} , "Jerry":{"SchoolName2": "school_name_2","Classname2":"class_name_2","teacher2":"teachers_name2"}}
   headers = ["Name", "School", "Class", "Teacher"]
```

by using Python "tabulate" I would like to achieve :

```
Name         School         Class         Teacher
--------  -------------  -----------    ------------
Tom       school_name_1   class_name_1  teachers_name1
Jerry     school_name_2   class_name_2  teachers_name2
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: And what is the problem to achieve that ?

Comment: Are you trying to print a response in that format, or convert to some tabular datatype. If the second option, which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to reach any of the datastructure needed for `tabulate`. The easier seems to be the one where [`headers` defines a list of column headers](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) and the data is a 2D list of values

Using a `list-comprehension` and flattening the values of each inner dict, that's quite simple:

```
from tabulate import tabulate

headers = ["Name", "School", "Class", "Teacher"]
values = {"Tom": {"SchoolName1": "school_name_1", "Classname1": "class_name_1", "teacher1": "teachers_name1"},
          "Jerry": {"SchoolName2": "school_name_2", "Classname2": "class_name_2", "teacher2": "teachers_name2"}}

values = [[name, *inner.values()] for name, inner in values.items()]

print(tabulate(values, headers=headers))
```

Giving the expected

```
Name    School         Class         Teacher
------  -------------  ------------  --------------
Tom     school_name_1  class_name_1  teachers_name1
Jerry   school_name_2  class_name_2  teachers_name2
```